# Only numeric characters from string on struts property

Tags: java, regex, struts2

I am new to struts, so I apologise for any incorrect terms etc.

I have an attribute that is pushed into a file. `attr.additionalNumber` this is a phone number with whitespace and a plus symbol e.g. `+123 4567 890`.

I have tried

`<s:property value="%{attr.additionalNumber.replaceAll('\^[a-zA-Z]', '')}" />`

but this returns a null string, not sure how to return `1234567890`? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `.replaceAll('[^0-9]+', '')`?

Comment: That worked, perfectly, thank you!